# Точка входа не найдена _ZNSt7_

Tags: c++, dll, mingw

Доброй ночи. 
учу C++ файл компилируется но при запуске выкидывает это
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как вылечить ошибку и может подскажите как подружить компилятор на моей системе win7-x64, MinGW с GtkSharp. При каждой компиляций закидываю в папку libstdc++-6 для работы MinGW.
Без него выдает ошибку точка входа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас не плохой вариант, пусть лежит в папке с программой она ж есть не просит. Второй вариант, положить `libstdc++.dll` в другую папку, и путь к ней прописать в переменную окружения `PATH`. Тогда Виндоуз бутем автоматически ее находить.
Третий вариант, скопировать ее в `system32`, на практике не рекомендовал бы так делать, но работать будет. [Подробнее про поиск DLL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/7d83bc18.aspx).

Ну и в корне проблему можно решить статическим включением `libstdc++` в исполняемый файл. Для этого нужно добавить флаги компиляции `-static-libstdc++` и `-static-libgcc`. После такой сборки никакие стандартные DLL с программой вам не понадобиться тягать.

Comment: спасибо за помощь.